# Error: No value passed for parameter 'data' inside MainActivity (Jetpack compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Hello stack overflow community.

I would like to pass (data class AndroidItem) parameter to Nav function inside MainActivity Class without empty data, how can i do? it must be like this **(data)** not **(data = )** and it shows error **(No value passed for parameter 'data')**.
i have tried but unfortunately i could not do. I know that there is similar questions about this subject but i want to help me right now

Here my code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        Diwaanka2022Theme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
                // here it must be like (data) only not (data = )
                Nav(data = )
            }
        }
    }
}
}


@Composable
data class AndroidItem(
    val ID: Int?,
    val ItemType: String?,
    val Price: Int?,
)


@Composable
fun Nav(data: AndroidItem) {
   val context = LocalContext.current
   val navController = rememberNavController()

   NavHost(
      navController = navController,
      startDestination = Screen.LoginScreen.route
   ) {

  composable(
     route = "Search_Screen_Details/{name}",
     arguments = listOf(
        navArgument(name = "name") {
           type = NavType.StringType
        }
     )
  ) {
        backStackEntry ->

     eee(
        navController,
        myName = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("name"),
        data
     )
  }
 }
}



@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun eee(navController: NavController, myName: String?, data: AndroidItem) {

val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()

BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
    sheetContent = {

        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(500.dp)
                .padding(15.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {

            val context = LocalContext.current

            Text(
                text = data.ID.toString(),
                fontSize = 25.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(vertical = 20.dp),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center

            )

            Button(onClick = {

            }) {
                Text(text = "welcome", fontSize = 22.sp)
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

        }
    }

) {

    Search_Screen_Details(navController, myName, scaffoldState)

}
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@SuppressLint("MutableCollectionMutableState")
@Composable
fun Search_Screen_Details(
    navController: NavController,
    myName: String?,
    scaffoldState: BottomSheetScaffoldState
) {

Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    
    val context = LocalContext.current
    
    if(myName == "all") {

        val baseUrl = "https://adeega.xisaabso.online/Api/android_all_customers_all.php"
        val android = Android()

        val data = remember {
            mutableStateOf(Android())
        }

        val stringRequest = StringRequest(baseUrl, { it ->
            val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
            val gson = gsonBuilder.create()
            gson.fromJson(it, Array<AndroidItem>::class.java)?.forEach {
                android.add(it)
            }
            data.value = android
        }, {
            Toast.makeText(context, it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }).apply {

            LazyColumn(
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(12.dp)
            ) {
                items(data.value) { item ->
                    MyCard(
                        data = item,
                        navController
                    )
                }
            } // END LazyColumn

        }// StringRequest

        val volleyRequest = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        volleyRequest.add(stringRequest)
    }
    
} // END Column

}



@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyCard(
    data : AndroidItem,
    navController: NavController,
    scaffoldState: BottomSheetScaffoldState
) {

Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
    elevation = 5.dp,
) {
    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(15.dp)
    ) {
        Column() {
            Text(
                text = data.ID.toString(),
                fontSize = 25.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
            
            Text(
                text = "Price: $" + data.Price,
                fontSize = 19.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
        }

    }//END Row

} //END Card

}
```

Comment: You need call `Nav(data = AndroidItem())`. By the way, `AndroidItem` shouldn't be marked `@Composable`. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Mr constorvar It shows same problem (no value passed for parameter 'ID', no value passed for parameter 'ItemType', no value passed for parameter 'price'?!!!

Comment: Transform `AndroidItem` model to `data class AndroidItem(
    val ID: Int? = null,
    val ItemType: String? = null,
    val Price: Int? = null
)`

Comment: Mr constorVar The result became null (in scaffoldState) inside eee fun (data.ID.toString) any other solution like viewmodel, how can I do with viewmodel?

Comment: There is no response data after changing to null value, any solution for my problem?!!